# android 2d game in java lags the moving objects

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview, 2d-games

So I am trying to make a 2d game using SurfaceView (It draws and moves the objects). The game is almost done but I am facing a major problem which is that my moving objects on the screen lag or get stuck (probably skipping frames). Maybe the canvas.drawBitmap() method is not drawing it fast enough. I have tried many things like accelerating hardware in manifests and using low quality images (which I'm converting to bitmap). And I DO NOT create bitmaps on each frame. I think the problem might be in the draw or update method. here are these methods:

UPDATE:

```
private void update() {

        background1.x -= backGroundSpeed * screenRatioX;
        background2.x -= backGroundSpeed * screenRatioX;

        if (background1.x + background1.background.getWidth() < 0){
            background1.x = screenX;
        }

        if (background2.x + background2.background.getWidth() < 0){
            background2.x = screenX;
        }

        if (flight.isGoingUp){
            flight.y -= flightSpeed * screenRatioY;
        }else{
            flight.y += flightSpeed * screenRatioY;
        }

        if (flight.y < 0){
            flight.y = 0;
        }

        if (flight.y >= (screenY - flight.height)){
            flight.y = screenY - flight.height;
        }

        for (Pig pig: pigs){

            pig.x -= pig.speed;

            if (pig.x + pig.normal_width < 0) {
                int bound = (int) (13 * screenRatioX);
                pig.speed = random.nextInt(bound);

                if (pig.speed < (backGroundSpeed * screenRatioX)+1) {
                    pig.speed = (int) (backGroundSpeed * screenRatioX)+1;
                }
                pig.x = screenX*2;
                pig.y = random.nextInt(screenY - pig.normal_height);
            }

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (Rect.intersects(pig.getCollisionShape(), flight.getCollisionShape())){
                    score++;
                    pig.x = -500;
                    if (!prefs.getBoolean("isMute", false)){
                        soundPool.play(point_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    }
                }

            }
        }, 500);

            }

        redPig.x -= redPig.redSpeed;

        if (redPig.x + redPig.red_width < 0) {
            int bound = (int) (25 * screenRatioX);
            redPig.redSpeed = random.nextInt(bound);

            if (redPig.redSpeed < (12 * screenRatioX)) {
                redPig.redSpeed = (int) (12 * screenRatioX);
            }
            redPigDistance = random.nextInt(6);
            if (redPigDistance < 2){
                redPigDistance = 2;
            }
            redPig.x = screenX*redPigDistance;
            redPig.y = random.nextInt(screenY - redPig.red_height);
        }

        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                if (Rect.intersects(redPig.getRedCollisionShape(), flight.getCollisionShape())){
                    isGameOver = true;
                    if (!prefs.getBoolean("isMute", false)){
                        soundPool.play(dead_sound, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    }
                }


            }
        }, 500);

        }
```

DRAW:

```
private void draw() {

        if (getHolder().getSurface().isValid()){

            Canvas canvas = getHolder().lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawBitmap(background1.background, background1.x, background1.y, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(background2.background, background2.x, background2.y, paint);

            if (isGameOver){
                isPlaying = false;
                canvas.drawBitmap(flight.getDead(), flight.x, flight.y, paint);
                getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                saveIfHighScore();
                waitBeforeExiting();
                return;
            }

                for (Pig pig : pigs) {
                    canvas.drawBitmap(pig.getPig(), pig.x, pig.y, paint);
                }

            canvas.drawBitmap(redPig.getRedPig(), redPig.x, redPig.y, paint);

            canvas.drawText("" + score, screenX/2f, (70*screenRatioY), paint);

            canvas.drawBitmap(flight.getFlight(), flight.x, flight.y, paint);

            getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Need code of the main loop. And you have to check canvas for null before draw

Comment: could you explain what code do you need to see? I think that the main loop is the UI thread (correct me if I'm wrong). and I added an if statement to check for null canvas. I didn't post alot of code here to keep it clean and straight forward but I will be happy to share more code if it would help you better understand my problem.

Comment: Also try to use SurfaceView

Comment: @Style-7 I am using SurfaceView